# Как добавить *.dll в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, include, lib

Пробую добавить ссылку на `dll` в проект `Qt`. Предварительно скачал либу для MiniGW.

Содержимое `pro`-файла

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/D:/test/sodium/lib/ -lsodium
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/D:/test/sodium/lib/ -lsodiumd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/D:/test/sodium/lib/ -lsodium

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/include

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/lib/libsodium.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/lib/libsodiumd.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/lib/sodium.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/lib/sodiumd.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/lib/libsodium.a
```

Пробую заинклудить либу - пишет `No such file or directory`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так все-таки dll или lib? И "заинклудить либу" - странно. Инклюдят заголовки.

Comment: Пардон, сделать чтобы работало)) добавить либу

Comment: "Пробую заинклудить либу - пишет No such file or directory" - как вы это делаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/D:/test/sodium/include
```

вот это вот $$PWD - означает каталог, в котором находится pro-файл.

Используете:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:/test/sodium/include
DEPENDPATH += D:/test/sodium/include
```

или

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/..относительный_путь_к_файлам
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/..относительный_путь_к_файлам
```

Для библиотек - аналогично

Для библиотеки libsodium-win32: скачал и распаковал, в моем случае папки bin/include/lib разместились в `D:\newfolder\libsodium-win32`

В pro-файл пишем:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:\newfolder\libsodium-win32\include
DEPENDPATH += D:\newfolder\libsodium-win32\include

LIBS += -LD:\newfolder\libsodium-win32\lib -llibsodium
```

после чего вот такой код нормально компилируется

```
#include <sodium.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char *ch1 = 0;
    unsigned char *ch2 = 0;

    crypto_hash_sha256(ch1, ch2, 1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Понятное дело что в функцию crypto_hash_sha256 необходимо передавать правильные значения, а не как в моем примере. Так как в этом случае программа "упадет" при попытке запуска.

Comment: А если у меня нет pro-файла

Comment: @Radzhab Если у Вас проект в QtCreator - то pro-файл обязан быть, с помощью него генерируются make-файлы и компилируется программа. Или используете Visual Studio?

Comment: Я использую Qt. Тут вопрос в другом. Есть либа. https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.10-mingw.tar.gz Как ее подрубить в Qt чтобы я могу использовать метод crypto_hash_sha256

Comment: @Radzhab дополнил ответ